# Android Studio. Optimize imports doesn't add missing imports

Tags: android-studio

*Code -> Optimize* imports removes unused imports, rearranges existing ones. But what if need to add some missing unambiguous classes? I could do that with `Ctrl + Shift + O` in Eclipse.

Android Studio version: 1.3.2